# Copy the row from one dataftrame and convert into column based on condition (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as: (df1)

```
Filename    Name    1_Info1     1_Info2     1_Info3
Filename_1  Name1   First Row   01-01-1900  Information_1st Row
Filename_2  Name2   Second Row  01-01-1901  Information_2nd Row
Filename_3  Name3   Third Row   01-01-1902  Information_3rd Row
```

The second dataframe as: df2 (Filename)

```
Model       Sample_ID2  Location1   Location2   Location3
MODEL_1     ID          10          40          70
MODEL_2     ID          20          50          80
MODEL_3     ID          30          60          90
MODEL_4     ID          31          61          91
MODEL_5     ID          32          62          92
MODEL_6     ID          33          63          93
```

The Filename of `df2` is matched within the column of `Filename` of `df1`, if it matches then the info from `df1` should be copied as columns in the `df2`.

so, the output should look like this if the name of the file is "Filename_1".

```
Model   Sample_ID2  Location1   Location2   Location3   Filename            Name    1_Info1         1_Info2         1_Info3
MODEL_1 ID          10          40          70          Filename_1          Name1   First Row       01-01-1900      Information_1st Row
MODEL_2 ID          20          50          80          Filename_1          Name1   First Row       01-01-1900      Information_1st Row
MODEL_3 ID          30          60          90          Filename_1          Name1   First Row       01-01-1900      Information_1st Row
MODEL_4 ID          31          61          91          Filename_1          Name1   First Row       01-01-1900      Information_1st Row
MODEL_5 ID          32          62          92          Filename_1          Name1   First Row       01-01-1900      Information_1st Row
MODEL_6 ID          33          63          93          Filename_1          Name1   First Row       01-01-1900      Information_1st Row
```

The filename is extracted already and searched and the row is concatenated but the only problem is to copy it in all rows (as this copies only in the first row)

Code is as follows:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Filename_1.text.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")

filename = os.path.basename("Filename_1.text.csv")
filename_new = filename.split('.')[0]

checked = ((df1[df1['Filename'] == filename_new]))

combined_df = pd.concat([df2, checked], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `ffill()`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Filename_1.text.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")

filename = os.path.basename("Filename_1.text.csv")
filename_new = filename.split('.')[0]

checked = ((df1[df1['Filename'] == filename_new]))

combined_df = pd.concat([df2, checked], axis=1)
cols = ['Filename','Name','1_Info1','1_Info2','1_Info3']
combined_df.loc[:,cols] = combined_df.loc[:,cols].ffill()
```